# binding string array to navigation bar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api

**Updated with Code:**
I have a string array in my controller like below,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {
$scope.menuitems =['Home','About'];
  };
});
```

I need to display it in the navigation pane (navigation should be on the leftside)
Below is my html code.

```
<body class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ng-repeat="x in menuitems track by $index">
            <li>{{x}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

I did get the string values bound to the navigation pane. It is showing text like {{x}}.

Kindly help

Comment: Add `complete` code of controller and HTML

Comment: Your code seems working properly.

Comment: @Alberto - Is it working for you? I am getting plain text like {{x}}

Comment: @Tushar -Updated with complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your javascript code `};` is unnecessary.
2. You haven't attached `controller` to the `div`.

Code.

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {
    $scope.menuitems = ['Home', 'About'];
    //}; // REMOVE THIS
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2" ng-controller="mycontroller">
<!--                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ng-repeat="x in menuitems track by $index">
        <li>{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
  <body class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
             <li ng-repeat="x in menuitems">{{x}}</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: People reading this answer would benefit from a description of why it's different than the asker's original code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified to make use of `mycontroller` in your html code.

```
<body class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-2" ng-controller='mycontroller'>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ng-repeat = "x in menuitems track by $index">
<li>{{x}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i guess the mistake is you should give the ng-repeat in li tag try it . It should work

Comment: Give the ng-controller as well

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Since you didn't post the whole code. I am expecting the all the necessary directives like ng-app and ng-controller are in place already in your code. If you are using HTML5 by using `<!DOCTYPE html>`, then syntax might give trouble sometimes. I gave it a try. Observe the line that I have marked with asterisks. I didn't end the script tag properly. And so I also got the {{x}} thing on the browser. When I replaced that line with properly ended script tags . It worked for me. You can may be try this way out. It worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> StackOverflow </title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
***** <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script src="soCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="soApp">
    <div class="col-md-2" ng-controller="soCtrl">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ng-repeat="x in menuitems track by $index">
        <li>{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```